# Using Global Variables in jQuery, but does not run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a this code

```
function myFunction(PostID){    
    // Get Image Src
    ImgSrc = $('#' + PostID + ' .myImg').attr('src');

    // Set Output
    var PostImgOutput = $('.inf-shf-pr .Post-img') ;

    //Put a src in out put
    PostImgOutput.attr({ 'src': ImgSrc });
}
```

Which runs, but if I use this:

```
var PostImgOutput = $('.inf-shf-pr .Post-img') ;
```

as a Global variable my code does not work. What is the problem?

```
// Set Output
var PostImgOutput = $('.inf-shf-pr .Post-img') ;

function myFunction(PostID) {
    // Get Image Src
    ImgSrc = $('#' + PostID + ' .myImg').attr('src');

    //Put a src in out put      
    PostImgOutput.attr({ 'src': ImgSrc });    
}
```

Comment: did you add `var PostImgOutput = $('.inf-shf-pr .Post-img') ;` inside document.ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global variable `PostImgOutput` must be inside your document.ready event handler. It's because the dom may not ready when you're referencing the `$('.inf-shf-pr .Post-img');`

```
// Set Output
var PostImgOutput;

$(function() {
  PostImgOutput = $('.inf-shf-pr .Post-img');
});

function myFunction(PostID){

    // Get Image Src
    ImgSrc = $('#'+PostID + ' .myImg').attr('src');

    //Put a src in out put

    PostImgOutput.attr({'src': ImgSrc });

}
```

In terms of previous condition:

Since the function is invoked at sometime later, at that time the DOM might be ready that's why it's working fine.

But when you place it outside the function, the statement will be executed as the browser comes across it. So at that time the DOM may not be ready. So assign value to `PostImgOutput` on `document.ready`

Answer (score 1):

That is because elements are not loaded when you are defining them globally. you need to wrap that code when dom is ready.

```
var PostImgOutput="";
$(function(){
  // Set Output
  PostImgOutput = $('.inf-shf-pr .Post-img') ;
});
```